# Need help to get started with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im getting started with React and im trying to start with basics. Now, this is my code

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>index</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js" type = "text/babel "></script>


</head> 

<body>
    <div id = 'try'></div>  
    <script type= "text/babel">
        const element = <Welcome />;
        ReactDOM.render(
          element,
          document.getElementById('try')
        );
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

and this is my **index.js**

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return <h1> hello</h1>;
    };

};
```

it is supposed to show me "hello" on index.html but the page stills blank, where is the error?

pd: also tried using "text/jsx" instead of "text/babel"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, this should work:

```js
class Welcome extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return <h1> hello</h1>;
    };

};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>  
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
 <div id="try"></div> 

 <script type="text/babel">
  const element = <Welcome/>
  ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById("try"));

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it works if i create the class on the html but if i try to import it, i get a cors policy error

Comment: I believe this is because the `index.js` file requests for the react class from the react.js CDN included, some browsers allow this to happen (in some cases) for example "firefox", chrome wouldn't, for reason beyond the scope of just a comment. I suggest you just go ahead and merge the two files, using your index.html to create the class instead, or create a React dev environment so you can separate your codebase.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `Welcome` without setting to const.

```
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Welcome />,
      document.getElementById('try')
    );
```